# Nested conditional not being recognized properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to nest a foreach within an if/else using Razor, but am having some issues with Razor claiming I'm missing a closing bracket. The code is below, where I've noted the "else" that isn't being syntax-highlighted by Visual Studio, which I'm guessing is where the issue lies:

```
    @if (ViewBag.user.administrativeRole != null)
    {
        <select name="administrativeRole" id="administrativeRole" class="selectInput" disabled="disabled">   
    }
    else // this else isn't syntax highlighted 
    {
        <select name="administrativeRole" id="administrativeRole" class="selectInput">
        @foreach (var role in ViewBag.roles)
        {
        if (ViewBag.user.administrativeRole != null && ViewBag.user.administrativeRole == role.superadmin)
        {
            <option value="@role.id" selected="selected">@role.name</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@role.id">@role.name</option>
        }
    }
}
</select>
```

which generates the following error:

> The if block is missing a closing "}"
>   character.  Make sure you have a
>   matching "}"  character for all the
>   "{" characters within this block, and
>   that none of the "}"  characters are
>   being interpreted as markup.

```
Line 58: @if (ViewBag.user.administrativeRole != null)
Line 59: {
Line 60:    <select name="administrativeRole" id="administrativeRole" class="selectInput" disabled="disabled">
```

Any thoughts? I'm guessing I just borked the syntax a bit, as I'm new to Razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `</select>` is in the wrong place.

It needs to be after the second `}`, at the same level as the `<select>`.

Because it isn't, Razor treats the last `}` as markup rather than code, so the outer `if` is not closed.

Also, you should call `Html.DropDown` instead.

Comment: Thank you much. Converted everything over to HTML helpers, made the whole mess a lot more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Slaks is on it with Html.DropDown, but if you're set on using the code the way you described it, try it like this:

```
    @{
        if (ViewBag.user.administrativeRole != null)
        {
            @:<select name="administrativeRole" id="administrativeRole" class="selectInput" disabled="disabled">   
        }
        else  
        {
            @:<select name="administrativeRole" id="administrativeRole" class="selectInput">
            foreach (var role in ViewBag.roles)
            {
                 if (ViewBag.user.administrativeRole != null ViewBag.user.administrativeRole == role.superadmin)
                 {
                     @:<option value="@role.id" selected="selected">@role.name</option>
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    @:<option value="@role.id">@role.name</option>
                 }
            }
        }
     }
 </select>
```

What this does is make a code block and then escape out the stuff you actually want to print to your markup.

Comment: You can just write `@if(...){...}`.  You don't need the outer code block.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your closing brace for the if. Maybe my phone display isn't scrolling to it but I see one missing